# Injecting HTML file from webdav

Tags: handlebars.js

So I can inject html code from files in a big-commerce template directory using for example

`{{> components/blog/post}}`

which injects post.html ...

but is there a way of calling and injecting a file stored on webdav FTP account using something like...

`{{> cdn 'webdav:/blog/post/post.html'}}`

(obviously that code is not right)

and also is it a safe thing to do? Or is it safer to leave all file in the template directory?